Unpivot or cross apply to show 2 values and difference between them?
Given the following table:
CREATE TABLE #CarPartSales (
        Make        VARCHAR(100)
,       Model       VARCHAR(100)
,       Part        VARCHAR(100)
,       Color       VARCHAR(100)
,       SalesYear   INT
,       TotalSold   DECIMAL(18,2)
,       Invoices    DECIMAL(18,2)
,       TotalPrice  DECIMAL(18,2)
)

INSERT INTO #CarPartSales VALUES 
    ('Chevy','Nova','Door','Red',2023, 120.00, 100.00, 900.50)
,   ('Chevy','Nova','Door','Red',2022, 100.00, 90.00, 850.25)
,   ('Chevy','Nova','Door','Black',2023, 70.00, 50.00, 450.75)
,   ('Chevy','Nova','Door','Black',2022, 20.00, 8.00, 200.00)
,   ('Ford','Fairlaine','Hood','White',2023, 100.00, 75.00, 780.35)
,   ('Ford','Fairlaine','Hood','White',2022, 70.00, 65.00, 650.20)
,   ('Dodge','Aspen','Fender','Green',2023, 30.00, 10.00, 125.00)
,   ('Dodge','Aspen','Fender','Green',2022, 10.00, 3.00, 75.55)

Is it possible to get output that looks like this:

I know I can do a bunch of union all like this:

SELECT      Make
,           Model
,           Part
,           Color
,           Category        = 'TotalSold'
,           PreviousValue   = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2022 THEN TotalSold END)
,           CurrentValue    = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2023 THEN TotalSold END)
,           ValueChange     = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2023 THEN TotalSold END) - SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2022 THEN TotalSold END)
FROM        #CarPartSales
GROUP BY    Make
,           Model
,           Part
,           Color

UNION ALL

SELECT      Make
,           Model
,           Part
,           Color
,           Category        = 'Invoices'
,           PreviousValue   = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2022 THEN Invoices END)
,           CurrentValue    = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2023 THEN Invoices END)
,           ValueChange     = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2023 THEN Invoices END) - SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2022 THEN Invoices END)
FROM        #CarPartSales
GROUP BY    Make
,           Model
,           Part
,           Color

UNION ALL

SELECT      Make
,           Model
,           Part
,           Color
,           Category        = 'TotalPrice'
,           PreviousValue   = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2022 THEN TotalPrice END)
,           CurrentValue    = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2023 THEN TotalPrice END)
,           ValueChange     = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2023 THEN TotalPrice END) - SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2022 THEN TotalPrice END)
FROM        #CarPartSales
GROUP BY    Make
,           Model
,           Part
,           Color

ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5

The issue is that I have 50 or so different Category values and was hoping there was a way to do this with UNPIVOT or CROSS APPLY, instead of 50 separate unions.
UPDATE:
I think I was able to get what I wanted with the following:

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT      SalesYear, Make, Model, Part, Color, ColumnName, value
FROM        (
    SELECT      SalesYear, Make, Model, Part, Color, TotalSold, Invoices, TotalPrice
    FROM        #CarPartSales
            ) AS SourceTable
UNPIVOT     (   
                value FOR ColumnName IN (
                        TotalSold
                ,       Invoices
                ,       TotalPrice)
            ) as Alias
)
SELECT      Make
,           Model
,           Part
,           Color
,           ColumnName
,           CurrentValue  = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2023 THEN value END)
,           PreviousValue = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2022 THEN value END)
,           ValueChange   = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2023 THEN value END) - SUM(CASE WHEN SalesYear = 2022 THEN value END)
FROM        cte
GROUP BY    Make
,           Model
,           Part
,           Color
,           ColumnName
ORDER BY    1,2,3,4,5


Do you actually care whether unpivot or cross apply is used? Or in fact are you just looking for a simpler solution? It doesn't pay to require the solution to use a specific technique unless it really does.

@DaleK I'm looking for a simpler solution. From what I gathered so far, it sounded like unpivot or cross apply was the way to go, but I'm open to any suggestions!

What happens if it's more than two years per car model? Does everything explode?

@siggemannen there will only be 2 years in the data .. current year and previous year

Side note, don't use single quotes (') for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They have some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you must delimit identify them use T-SQL's identifier, brackets ([]), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (").

Doing the unpivoting before the aggregation won't be very efficient performance wise as you will be expanding the number of rows in #CarPartSales  out by 50 x if 50 different columns and then needing to re-aggregate them without being able to take advantage of any order provided by existing indexes. Performance wise will probably be best to do the aggregation and then unpivot that. That is significantly more typing though as you would need PreviousTotalSold, CurrentTotalSold,PreviousInvoices, CurrentInvoices, PreviousTotalPrice, CurrentTotalPrice, ...

@MartinSmith fortunately #CarPartSales is fairly small temp table. My solution runs in under a few seconds. There are only 50 or so rows, with the 50 or so different categories I need to unpivot.

Also please don't use images, use the table markdown the editor provides.

Yes, you need to unpivot (preferably using CROSS APPLY (VALUES as this is more flexible) then re-pivot (using GROUP BY and SUM(CASE again this is more flexible).
SELECT
  cps.Make,
  cps.Model,
  cps.Part,
  cps.Color,
  v.Category,
  PreviousValue = SUM(CASE WHEN cps.SalesYear = 2022 THEN v.Value END),
  CurrentValue = SUM(CASE WHEN cps.SalesYear = 2023 THEN v.Value END),
  ValueChange = SUM(CASE WHEN cps.SalesYear = 2023 THEN v.Value END) - SUM(CASE WHEN cps.SalesYear = 2022 THEN v.Value END)
FROM #CarPartSales cps
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('TotalSold',  cps.TotalSold),
    ('Invoices',   cps.Invoices),
    ('TotalPrice', cps.TotalPrice)
) v(Category, Value)
GROUP BY
  cps.Make,
  cps.Model,
  cps.Part,
  cps.Color,
  v.Category;

db<>fiddle

I thing a LAG()-based solution would better handle the general case over multiple years. (Fiddle, with some extra 2020 and 2021 test data)

True but then how would you do the columns? You'd need to keep them in separate rows (which I agree is more normalized) but not what OP asked.

I was thinking unpivot (cross apply) as posted, but with lag() used for the current/prior logic. Ended up being more complicated (requiring a subquery) if querying for just one year. I came up with a self join alternative that handles both single-year and multi-year scenarios. But yes, the OP only asked for one year.

Thank you .. this is exactly what I had in mind. I just didn't know how to make it work without the cte from my attempted solution.

You can self-join the current year data with the prior-year data and then use a CROSS APPLY( VALUES... ) to unpivot the data.  (A formal UNPIVOT can also be used, but sometimes this other technique is cleaner.)
SELECT
  cps.Make,
  cps.Model,
  cps.Part,
  cps.Color,
  cps.SalesYear,
  v.Category,
  v.PreviousValue,
  v.CurrentValue,
  v.CurrentValue - v.PreviousValue AS ValueChange
FROM #CarPartSales cps
LEFT JOIN #CarPartSales priorcps
    ON priorcps.Make = cps.Make
    AND priorcps.Model = cps.Model
    AND priorcps.Part = cps.Part
    AND priorcps.Color = cps.Color
    AND priorcps.SalesYear = cps.SalesYear - 1
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('TotalSold',  cps.TotalSold,  priorcps.TotalSold),
    ('Invoices',   cps.Invoices,   priorcps.Invoices),
    ('TotalPrice', cps.TotalPrice, priorcps.TotalPrice)
) v(Category, CurrentValue, PreviousValue)
WHERE cps.SalesYear = 2023
ORDER BY
  cps.Make,
  cps.Model,
  cps.Part,
  cps.Color,
  cps.SalesYear,
  v.Category;

Results:



Make
Model
Part
Color
SalesYear
Category
PreviousValue
CurrentValue
ValueChange




Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2023
Invoices
8.00
50.00
42.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2023
TotalPrice
200.00
450.75
250.75


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2023
TotalSold
20.00
70.00
50.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Red
2023
Invoices
90.00
100.00
10.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Red
2023
TotalPrice
850.25
900.50
50.25


Chevy
Nova
Door
Red
2023
TotalSold
100.00
120.00
20.00


Dodge
Aspen
Fender
Green
2023
Invoices
3.00
10.00
7.00


Dodge
Aspen
Fender
Green
2023
TotalPrice
75.55
125.00
49.45


Dodge
Aspen
Fender
Green
2023
TotalSold
10.00
30.00
20.00


Ford
Fairlaine
Hood
White
2023
Invoices
65.00
75.00
10.00


Ford
Fairlaine
Hood
White
2023
TotalPrice
650.20
780.35
130.15


Ford
Fairlaine
Hood
White
2023
TotalSold
70.00
100.00
30.00



If you remove the WHERE cps.SalesYear = 2023 condition, you can get data across multiple years.
Multi-year results with some extra data (partial):



Make
Model
Part
Color
SalesYear
Category
PreviousValue
CurrentValue
ValueChange




Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2020
Invoices
null
4.00
null


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2020
TotalPrice
null
125.00
null


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2020
TotalSold
null
12.00
null


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2021
Invoices
4.00
6.00
2.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2021
TotalPrice
125.00
150.00
25.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2021
TotalSold
12.00
15.00
3.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2022
Invoices
6.00
8.00
2.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2022
TotalPrice
150.00
200.00
50.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2022
TotalSold
15.00
20.00
5.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2023
Invoices
8.00
50.00
42.00


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2023
TotalPrice
200.00
450.75
250.75


Chevy
Nova
Door
Black
2023
TotalSold
20.00
70.00
50.00


...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...



See this db<>fiddle.
